# Passing context variable in generic.UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I have a template begining with:

```
{% extends load_template %}
```

the load_template takes values from this condition in my view

```
        if user == 'guest':
            load_template = 'damage/menus/menu.html'
        else:
            load_template = 'damage/menus/sidebarmenu.html'
```

I use a generic.UpdateView for update (which returns an error , because load_template variable hasn't got a value)
How can I pass value to this variable in this UpdateView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can patch the [**`get_context_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import UpdateView

class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if somecondition:
            load_template = 'damage/menus/menu.html'
        else:
            load_template = 'damage/menus/sidebarmenu.html'
        context['load_template'] = load_template
        return context
```

This will thus add a variable named `load_template` to the context. Note that `user` is not defined here. The user that is logged in, is the `self.request.user`. For example:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import UpdateView

class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            load_template = 'damage/menus/menu.html'
        else:
            load_template = 'damage/menus/sidebarmenu.html'
        context['load_template'] = load_template
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you my friend